# Rendering frames from a webcam to a DirectX 11 texture

Tags: c++, directx, directx-11, render-to-texture, textureview

I am having difficulty updating a DirectX 11 texture with the image data from a webcam frame buffer in memory. I've managed to create a texture from a single frame in the buffer but as the buffer is overwritten with the next frame the texture doesn't update. So I'm left with a snap shot image rather than a live stream which I'm after.

I am trying to use the Map/Unmap methods for updating an ID3D11Texture2D resource because that is supposedly more efficient than using the UpdateSubresource method. I haven't managed to get either to work. I'm new to DirectX and I just can't find a good explanation anywhere on how to accomplish this.

Create texture here:

```
bool CreateCamTexture(ID3D11ShaderResourceView** out_srv, RGBQUAD* ptrimg, int* image_width, int* image_height)
{

    ZeroMemory(&desc, sizeof(desc));
    desc.Width = *image_width;
    desc.Height = *image_height;
    desc.MipLevels = 1;
    desc.ArraySize = 1;
    desc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM;
    desc.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
    desc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DYNAMIC;
    desc.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_SHADER_RESOURCE;
    desc.CPUAccessFlags = D3D11_CPU_ACCESS_WRITE;

    std::cout << ptrimg << std::endl;
    subResource.pSysMem = ptrimg;
    subResource.SysMemPitch = desc.Width * 4;
    subResource.SysMemSlicePitch = 0;
    g_pd3dDevice->CreateTexture2D(&desc, &subResource, &pTexture);

    ZeroMemory(&srvDesc, sizeof(srvDesc));
    srvDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM;
    srvDesc.ViewDimension = D3D11_SRV_DIMENSION_TEXTURE2D;
    srvDesc.Texture2D.MipLevels = desc.MipLevels;
    srvDesc.Texture2D.MostDetailedMip = 0;
    g_pd3dDevice->CreateShaderResourceView(pTexture, &srvDesc, out_srv);
    if (pTexture != NULL) {
        pTexture->Release();
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "pTexture is NULL ShaderResourceView not created" << std::endl;
    }

    return true;
}
bool CreateDeviceD3D(HWND hWnd)
{
    // Setup swap chain
    DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC sd;
    ZeroMemory(&sd, sizeof(sd));
    sd.BufferCount = 2;
    sd.BufferDesc.Width = 0;
    sd.BufferDesc.Height = 0;
    sd.BufferDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM;
    sd.BufferDesc.RefreshRate.Numerator = 60;
    sd.BufferDesc.RefreshRate.Denominator = 1;
    sd.Flags = DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_FLAG_ALLOW_MODE_SWITCH;
    sd.BufferUsage = DXGI_USAGE_RENDER_TARGET_OUTPUT;
    sd.OutputWindow = hWnd;
    sd.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
    sd.SampleDesc.Quality = 0;
    sd.Windowed = TRUE;
    sd.SwapEffect = DXGI_SWAP_EFFECT_DISCARD;

    UINT createDeviceFlags = 0;
    createDeviceFlags |= D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_DEBUG;
    D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL featureLevel;
    const D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL featureLevelArray[2] = { D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_11_0, D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_10_0, };
```

Attempting to Map/Unmap texture:

```
void UpdateCamTexture() {
    D3D11_MAPPED_SUBRESOURCE mappedResource;

    ZeroMemory(&mappedResource, sizeof(D3D11_MAPPED_SUBRESOURCE));
    
    g_pd3dDeviceContext->Map(
        pTexture,
        0, //0,
        D3D11_MAP_WRITE_DISCARD,
        0,
        &mappedResource);
    memcpy(mappedResource.pData, listener_instance.pImgData, sizeof(listener_instance.pImgData));
    //  Reenable GPU access to the vertex buffer data.
    g_pd3dDeviceContext->Unmap(pTexture, 0);
    std::cout << "texture updated" << std::endl;
}
```

I don't get an error, the image is just black. I don't have debug layer enabled though.

Comment: Why are you releasing texture after creation? `pTexture->Release();`

Comment: I'm no longer releasing the texture after creation and I still can't update it.

Answer (score 1):

Calling `sizeof` on a pointer `listener_instance.pImgData` is not what you want since it returns the size of a pointer type (8 on x64 architecture) and not size of array pointed by the pointer. Calling `memcpy` with the image data size in bytes is also not completely correct solution. See [here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/187638/using-id3d11devicecontextmap-to-update-a-dynamic-texture-results-in-offset-or) for more details.
I will copy the answer from there just in case it's deleted.

Maximus Minimus's answer:

Check the returned pitch from your map call - you're assuming it's `width * 4` (for 32-bit RGBA) but it may not be (particularly if your texture is not a power of 2 or it's width is not a multiple of 4).

You can only `memcpy` the entire block in one operation if pitch is equal to width * number of bytes in the format. Otherwise you must `memcpy` one row at a time.

Sample code, excuse C-isms:

assumes that src and dst are 32-bit RGBA data

```
unsigned *src; // this comes from whatever your input is
unsigned *dst = (unsigned *) msr.pData; // msr is a D3D11_MAPPED_SUBRESOURCE derived from ID3D11DeviceContext::Map
```

width and height come from `ID3D11Texture2D::GetDesc`

```
for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
{
    memcpy (dst, src, width * 4); // copy one row at a time because msr.RowPitch may be != (width * 4)
    dst += msr.RowPitch >> 2; // msr.RowPitch is in bytes so for 32-bit data we divide by 4 (or downshift by 2, same thing)
    src += width; // assumes pitch of source data is equal to width * 4
}
```

You can, of course, also include a test for if `(msr.RowPitch == width * 4)` and do a single `memcpy` of the entire thing if it's true.